# JavaScript code for reading divs off an array of images

Tags: javascript

I created arrays for each image and then i combined the images using a another array and i want to move a div across the array along to the next images. I need some JavaScript code to allow me to do this. If that makes sense?

They are all eyes of images in the array hence the code below that i'm showing to give anyone an idea.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var move = 0;
//Step 1 : Create a new array for each pair of eyes i add
var eyes1 = new Array("100px", "0px 0px");
var eyes2 = new Array("100px", "-100px 0px");
var eyes3 = new Array("100px", "-200px 0px");
var eyes4 = new Array("100px", "-300px 0px");
var eyes5 = new Array("100px", "-400px 0px");
var eyes6 = new Array("100px", "-500px 0px");
var eyes7 = new Array("100px", "-600px 0px");
var eyes8 = new Array("100px", "-700px 0px");
var eyes9 = new Array("100px", "-800px 0px");
var eyes10 = new Array("100px", "-900px 0px");
var eyes11 = new Array("100px", "-1000px 0px");
var eyes12 = new Array("100px", "-1100px 0px");

//Step 2: add the pair of eyes from above to this array
var allEyes = new Array(eyes1, eyes2, eyes3, eyes4, eyes5, eyes6, eyes7, eyes8, eyes9, eyes10, eyes11, eyes12 );
```

??

Comment: from the "-*00px 0px" part i assume you are using an image sprite, so you want to show different parts of this sprite in your div? sorry i dont get your problem

Comment: Yeh i'm using an image strip and i want to show different parts of my strip in my div each time

Comment: Use `['100px', '0px 0px']` instead of `new Array("100px", "0px 0px")`.

Comment: Yeh sorry realise now reading it doesn't make alot of sense. I have an image strip made up of all different sets of eyes. I want to move a div along it showing a different set if eyes each time. Above in my code the new arrays capture the movement along the strip by 100px.

Answer (score 0):

Please add a bit more detail to your question because I am not quite sure I understand what you are trying to do. Based on the info you have given thus far here is some JavaScript that loops through an array and changes the content of a `div` tag based on what is in the array.  I set this to loop every 5 seconds, but you can use whatever control mechanism you want.

```
i = 0;

function loopImages(){
    document.getElementById('your_div_id').innerHTML = images[i%images.length];
    i++;
    setTimeout(loopImages, 5000);
}
```

Comment: Don't ever use the string for the first argument to `setTimeout()` -- it causes a nasty eval which you want to avoid... Much easier to just pass the function: `setTimeout(loopImages, 5000)` would work fine

Comment: The overall program is to show different parts of the eyes every time by a click of a button rather than a timed movement. I have numerous other image strips that will make up a whole face. So so i want to control when i change the image

Answer (score 0):

How about this

```
var eyesState = 0;
var eyes = [["100px", "0px 0px"]
            ["100px", "-100px 0px"],
            ["100px", "-200px 0px"],
            ["100px", "-300px 0px"],
            ["100px", "-400px 0px"],
            ["100px", "-500px 0px"],
            ["100px", "-600px 0px"],
            ["100px", "-700px 0px"],
            ["100px", "-800px 0px"],
            ["100px", "-900px 0px"],
            ["100px", "-1000px 0px"],
            ["100px", "-1100px 0px"]];
var eyesDiv = document.getElementById('eyes');
function eyesButtonOnClick(){
    eyesState = (eyesState+1)%eyes.length;
    //i am not sure what the first 100px are for
    //it might be the width of those eye then use something like
//  eyesDiv.style.width = eyes[eyeState][0];
    eyesDiv.style.backgroundPosition = eyes[eyesState][1];
}
//  bind this function to your button eg.
//  via button.onclick or per some js framework
```

Answer (score 0):

Vprimachenko's answer you received is also a good answer if this is what you need (and much simpler).
This question does need more details. From the values you have in the arrays I suspect that you are having a div over a long image and you wish to move either the div across the image or to have the div static and move the image as div background to display only a part of it at the time? The latter makes more sense to me as the div stays in the same position.

Assuming that you have a div in your html page like:

```
<div id="eyesState"></div>
```

and a link to click on to request the next part of the image to be displayed in the div like:

```
<a href="javascript:getNextPart();">Get the next part of the image</a>
```

then all you need is the javascript function that displays the next part of the long image:

```
function getNextPart() {
    // This gets the content of your html div eyesState in the javascript function
    // for processing.
    var magicdiv = document.getElementById("eyesState");
    // This empties the div just in case it may not be empty already (if you are
    // already displaying some part of image... you want to remove this before placing
    // the next part of image otherwise it will display it on top of the prev image.
    magicdiv.innerHTML= "";
    // Since all you do is move the background image of the div, you need to set this
    // into the Style attribute of this div. Might need to set the Weight style too 
    // and others. Check out the img value below
    var backgroundimg = "background-position:" + allEyes[img][1];
    magicdiv.setAttribute("style", backgroundimg);
    // img basically tells you which next bit of image from your AllEyes array will be
    // displayed.
    if (img == AllEyes.length)
      img = 0;
    else
      img++ ; 
}
```

Might need to set img to 0 outside your function.